# Argument data type money is invalid for argument 2 of EncryptByKey function

Tags: mysql, sql, encryption

I am trying to do an Symetric Encryption of a column that contains numbers and decimals that are of the data type: money. I have created a new column for my encryption and set it to a Varchar data type. My goal is to encrypt one column and place it here.

Comment: *that are of the data type: money.* No such datatype in MySQL. Check your DBMS name carefully.

Answer (score 0):

It was needed to change the data type and drop the keys it interacts with